# AppEngine can't connect to VPC when redeployed

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm running Python app in AppEngine Standard Environment which is using Redis (Memorystore instance [connected via VPC](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/connecting-vpc)).

When I deploy a new version (meaning the value of `version` parameter for `gcloud beta app deploy` command) of the app, the VPC connection works fine. However when I redeploy the existing version again, the VPC connection stops working (Redis connnection times out: `Error 110 connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6379. Connection timed out.`)

The app has some Historical Reasons where it relies on a specific version name of the deployed version, plus it's using Canary Deployment (small percentage of traffic goes to new version) via the builtin AppEngine feature for splitting traffic, which has hardcoded `version` name too, so redeployment to Canary is unusable.

Obvious answer is fixing the Historical Reasons and deployment (which has low priority unfortunately), so is there any way how to fix/workaround this issue in the meantime?

app.yaml:

```
runtime: python38

instance_class: F4
automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 5
  min_instances: 1

inbound_services:
  - warmup

service:
  py3

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always

includes:
  - env_vars.yaml

vpc_access_connector:
  name: projects/xxx/locations/europe-west2/connectors/yyy
```

deployment log:

```
$ gcloud beta app deploy ./app.yaml --no-promote --version=v3-0-2 --verbosity=debug
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.beta.app.deploy] with arguments: [--no-promote: "false", --verbosity: "debug", --version: "v3-0-2", DEPLOYABLES:1: "[u'./app.yaml']"]
INFO: Refreshing access_token
DEBUG: API endpoint: [https://appengine.googleapis.com/], API version: [v1beta]
Services to deploy:

descriptor:      [/Users/yed/dev/xxx/appname/beapplication/app.yaml]
source:          [/Users/yed/dev/xxx/appname/beapplication]
target project:  [appname]
target service:  [py3]
target version:  [v3-0-2]
target url:      [https://v3-0-2-dot-py3-dot-appname.appspot.com]


     (add --promote if you also want to make this service available from
     [https://py3-dot-appname.appspot.com])

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

DEBUG: No bucket specified, retrieving default bucket.
DEBUG: Using bucket [gs://staging.appname.appspot.com].
Beginning deployment of service [py3]...
INFO: Using ignore file at [/Users/yed/dev/xxx/appname/beapplication/.gcloudignore].
DEBUG: Skipping file [pyproject.toml]
...
INFO: Incremental upload skipped 98.62% of data
...
File upload done.
INFO: Manifest: [{u'application/_config/dfp.py': {...list of files...}}]
DEBUG: Converted YAML to JSON: "{
  "automaticScaling": {
    "standardSchedulerSettings": {
      "maxInstances": 5, 
      "minInstances": 1
    }
  }, 
  "entrypoint": {
    "shell": ""
  }, 
  "envVariables": {
    "REDIS_HOST": "xxx", 
  }, 
  "handlers": [
    {
      "script": {
        "scriptPath": "auto"
      }, 
      "securityLevel": "SECURE_ALWAYS", 
      "urlRegex": "/.*"
    }
  ], 
  "inboundServices": [
    "INBOUND_SERVICE_WARMUP"
  ], 
  "instanceClass": "F4", 
  "runtime": "python38", 
  "vpcAccessConnector": {
    "name": "projects/appname/locations/europe-west2/connectors/xxx"
  }
}"
DEBUG: Operation [apps/appname/operations/xxx] not complete. Waiting to retry.       
Updating service [py3]...⠏DEBUG: Operation [apps/appname/operations/xxx] complete. Result: {                    
    "response": {
        "runtimeChannel": "default", 
        "versionUrl": "https://v3-0-2-dot-py3-dot-appname.appspot.com", 
        "name": "apps/appname/services/py3/versions/v3-0-2", 
        "servingStatus": "SERVING", 
        "createTime": "2020-01-09T02:08:35Z", 
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1beta.Version", 
        "inboundServices": [
            "INBOUND_SERVICE_WARMUP"
        ], 
        "threadsafe": true, 
        "instanceClass": "F4", 
        "env": "standard", 
        "automaticScaling": {
            "standardSchedulerSettings": {
                "minInstances": 1, 
                "maxInstances": 5
            }
        }, 
        "runtime": "python38", 
        "id": "v3-0-2", 
        "network": {}
    }, 
    "done": true, 
    "name": "apps/appname/operations/xxx", 
    "metadata": {
        "target": "apps/appname/services/py3/versions/v3-0-2", 
        "method": "google.appengine.v1beta.Versions.CreateVersion", 
        "user": "xxx", 
        "insertTime": "2020-01-09T02:07:30.085Z", 
        "endTime": "2020-01-09T02:08:37.860Z", 
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1beta.OperationMetadataV1Beta"
    }
}
Updating service [py3]...done.                                                                                                                                
INFO: Not stopping previous version because new version was not promoted.
Deployed service [py3] to [https://v3-0-2-dot-py3-dot-appname.appspot.com]

You can stream logs from the command line by running:
  $ gcloud app logs tail -s py3

To view your application in the web browser run:
  $ gcloud app browse -s py3
INFO: Display format: "none"
```

Comment: what is the content of your `app.yaml` file? Do you override existing version when you redeploy?

Comment: `app.yaml` added. Yes the problem occurs only when I deploy over existing version, deploying new different version is fine.

Comment: Could you share the output of the deploy with the [`--verbosity="debug"`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--verbosity) flag? also, you may want to ensure that you are using the most recent version of the Cloud SDK

Comment: @rsalinas deployment log added. SDK is up-to-date.

Comment: I think that is an unexpected side effect. I recommend you to open a case either to the support (if you have a subscription) or to the [public tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)

Comment: I guess that's the best option I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer tthis myself, just to close this question:

After some intensive googling I stumbled upon the same issue at [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/975697/google-appengine-standard-routing-via-vpc-access-connector), and the answer there seems to help:

> Our solution ended up being adding Compute Network User permissions to the profile executing the deployment. Unfortunately this permissions error isn't logged out to us but rather internal to Google. This appeared to solve all issues we were experiencing in the Standard Environment. Also make sure to use `gcloud beta app deploy`